# Single child and "onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child"

Tags: reactjs

If I understand React's `children` prop correctly:

- `children` is normally an array, but if there's only one child, it gives that single child. ([source](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html))
- `children` is "opaque," so application code apparently shouldn't rely on this. ([source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children))
- [`React.children.count`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.count) returns `1` if there's only one child.
- [`React.children.only`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.only) should get the only child.

Based on that, I would expect the following code to work:

```
const Sample = ({children, ...props}) => {
  if (React.Children.count(children) === 1) {
    doSomethingWith(React.Children.only(children));
  }

  // etc.
};

<Sample>Hello, world!<Sample>;
```

Instead, it throws the following error:

> onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that React.Children.only expects the only child to be a valid React *element*, not a renderable string or number.

I don't really understand the rationale or use case for this, but React 15.3.1 at least [improves the error message](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v15.3.1/src/isomorphic/children/onlyChild.js) ("React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child").

[React issue #1104](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1104) discusses this further.

The solution is apparently to ignore `React.Children.only` and go ahead and access the single `children` element directly:

```
  if (React.Children.count(children) === 1) {
    doSomethingWith(children);
  }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. This is most definitely not clear from the docs.